# Selecting distinct values inside a JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a json data which has year, month and date. Here I want to select unique dates. Like date 6 and month 8 occurs 3 times. But I want only once

```
[
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 5
   },
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 6
   },

   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 6
   },

   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 6
   },
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 8
   },
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 9
   },
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 9
   },
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 10
   },
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 12
   },
   {
       "year": 2016,
       "month": 8,
       "date": 13
   },
]
```

Below code is what I have come up with. And this is working correctly. But I doubt that this is not the most optimum way to achieve this. And this will hit performance when the JSON size will grow.

```
function getDistinctDate(dates) {
    let lookup = [];
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        let jsontext = `{"year" : ${dates[i].year}, "month": ${dates[i].month}, "date": ${dates[i].date}}`;
        if (lookup.indexOf(jsontext) === -1) {
            lookup.push(jsontext)
            result.push(JSON.parse(jsontext));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to know if there is a better way of achieving this

Comment: Good place for code reviewing is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks.I was not aware.  I will post such questions in future in codereview platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a JSON Array you're going to have to loop over every item (unless the moment you find your condition you can stop, which is not the case here).  Since you must check every item for your condition, what you are doing is fine, but when you add it to an array and then call indexOf on that array, you  are now essentially looping an array again looking for your item, we can optimize this by using an object.

```
function getDistinctDate(dates) {
    let lookup = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        let jsontext = `{"year" : ${dates[i].year}, "month": ${dates[i].month}, "date": ${dates[i].date}}`;
        lookup[jsontext] = true;
    }
    return Object.keys(lookup);
}
```

This will create an object that has only the unique strings as keys (and since you are setting up the string format with 'jsontext' we can safely use that as our unique identifier)
And then when it's finished looping and creating our lookup return object, we can call Object.keys on it which will return back an array of all the keys in this object - which is what you're looking for in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I was exactly looking for, but not able to figure out how. Working perfectly now. Thanks